# Bazel: pass a build time variable to C++ program

Tags: c++, bazel

I've this C++ program that prints the value of `VERSION` string:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Version: " << VERSION << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to change the value of `VERSION` (a string) at build time. This is my Bazel config that contains a default value for `VERSION` as `local_defines`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],   
    local_defines = ["VERSION=\\\"alpha\\\""],
)
```

When I call it like this, it still prints `alpha` and NOT the new value I'm passing for `VERSION`.

```
bazel run --define VERSION=beta main
INFO: Analyzed target //:main (1 packages loaded, 2 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.965s, Critical Path: 0.80s
INFO: 4 processes: 2 internal, 2 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4 total actions
Version: alpha
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: I cleaned and ran `bazel run main --define VERSION=beta` again. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cc_binary.local_defines` and the `--define` flag are separate things, even though they share the same name. `local_defines` supports ["Make" variable substitution](https://bazel.build/reference/be/make-variables), which means this will work: `local_defines = ["VERSION=\\\"$(VERSION)\\\""]`.

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there a way to define a default value for `VERSION` in the Bazel BUILD file?

Comment: No. You could write a custom rule and do it in Starlark, or do it with a line like `build --define VERSION=default` in `.bazelrc` (which can be overridden by flags you pass on the command line).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `--workspace_status_command` is an option for you. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/JulianSchmid/example-bazel-add-git-hash).